# Continuity Equation on a Non-Ideal System

Tags: electromagnetism, conservation-laws, electrical-resistance, dissipation

I recently watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIuoFAW9H3E) on the diffusion equation for neutrons in a fissile material, and at about 2:30 minutes into the video, the author points out that the right hand side of the continuity equation (bottom) should not be 0 because new neutrons are created and consumed in each reaction.
$$\left \langle \vec{\nabla} , \vec{J} \right \rangle + \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial\mathrm{t}} = 0$$

The question is, for electromagnetism, why don't we include a resistive term on the right hand side of the equation that accounts for the conversion of electricity to heat? What would the equation look like in this particular case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be conflating charge with energy. There would only be need for additional terms in the charge continuity equation if there were generation or destruction of charge, resulting in charge not being conserved.

Conversion between electromagnetic energy and other forms of energy is essentially built into Maxwell's equations. It manifests in the $\mathbf J \cdot \mathbf E$ term of [Poynting's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting%27s_theorem), a continuity equation for electromagnetic energy:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \mathbf \nabla \cdot \mathbf S = -\mathbf J \cdot \mathbf E$$
where $u$ is the electromagnetic energy density and $\mathbf S$ is the Poynting vector. $\mathbf J \cdot \mathbf E$ is the electromagnetic energy "destroyed" (e.g. converted to heat) per unit volume, and is responsible for [Joule heating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_heating).